# best-fit wireframe in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, curve-fitting, contour

I'm operating with a 3-D list data in matplotlib.

Trying to plot a best-fitted `wireframe`.

My data infrastructure(doesn't represent actual data):

```
x=[1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 2.5, 2,3, 2.8]
y=[167.0, 180.3, 177.8,160.4,179.6, 154.3]
z=[-0.3, -0.8, -0.75, -1.21, -1.65, -0.68]
```

So far, I've been able to get a fitted wireframe using

```
   data = np.c_[x,y,z]  
   mn = np.min(data, axis=0)  
   mx = np.max(data, axis=0)  
   X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0], 20), np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1], 20))   
   XX = X.flatten()  
   YY = Y.flatten()  
   # best-fit quadratic curve  
   A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]  
   C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])  
   #evaluating on grid    
   Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)
```

So far, I obtained a wireframe-fit like(although can not `print` the equation on canvas):
[image: wireframe-fit]

> > How can I be sure whether I've fitted in right way, in right equation ? How am I to check the goodness-of-fit may be ? Any ideas on how can I superpose this curve with a contour would be also very nice.

please help.
thank you

Comment: are you using any equation to fit your data? if so post it along with the entire code you have used.

Comment: @ThePredator speaking about the equation, how would I know if I'm using the right equation to get a good-fit over the data. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `griddata()`. You can look at the following website, which does exactly what you are looking for: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Gridding_irregularly_spaced_data

Comment: any ideas on justifying the curve fit. !? 'm trying the contour part however not getting it properly.

Comment: `griddata()` merely *interpolates* your data to a regular grid using the specific 2D polinomial fit which you choose. All the contourplots also do the same. Points are interpolated between data. However, generally contourplots do interpolations on regularly spaced data. This is were grid data comes in. Your data is not fit to a polynomial (except within nearest neighbour points). You can think of this as a piece-wise polynomial fit except in 2D.

Comment: From the last example on that link. `grid, bins, binloc = griddata.griddata(x, y, z, binsize=binsize)` is raising an error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'griddata'`.